# Create drop down control containing page's named anchors

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a dynamically created page (read from database values) with grouped information.  I wanted to add **named anchors** as each group is created. (Regular anchors will appear on the page also.)

I was hoping to find a jQuery plug or codeset example that could automatically generate and populate a drop down control for the page that provides the navigation to the named anchors.

Thanks for any pointers or examples.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.anchorsToSelect = function(selector) {
        selector = selector || 'a[name]';

        this.html($(selector).map(function(){
            return '<option value="#' + this.name + '">' + $(this).text();
        }).get().join('</option>'));

        this.bind('change', function(){
            location.hash = $(this).val();
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage: `$('select#MyDropDown').anchorsToSelect();`